# How to add extra text boxes in flutter

Tags: flutter

https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/02/25/using-firebase-auth-in-flutter/

Hi all I am new to flutter and following the above guide.

> We create four textformfields and each field will contain its own validation. After that we create a Raisedbutton widget that will be the submit button:

How do I actually do this as this only adds 1? Where do I add the others, within this widget. Sorry for noob question

```
    return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: nameController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Enter User Name",
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
              ),
              // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Enter User Name';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can reference https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation

code snippet

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  child: TextFormField(
    controller: passwordController,
    obscureText: true,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: "Enter password",
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
    ),
    // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
    validator: (value) {
      if (value.isEmpty) {
        return 'Enter password';
      }
      return null;
    },
  ),
),
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {}
  },
  child: Text('Submit'),
)
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController ageController = TextEditingController();

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    nameController.dispose();
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    ageController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: nameController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Enter User Name",
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
                // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Enter User Name';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: emailController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Enter Email",
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
                // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Enter Email';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: ageController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Enter age",
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
                // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Enter age';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: passwordController,
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Enter password",
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
                // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Enter password';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {}
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
            )
          ]))),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice! When I did this https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/02/25/using-firebase-auth-in-flutter/ I assumed people would just copy the one field already added in the tutorial and create 3 others